# Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName()

Tags: php, object, curl

I'm making a CURL request, this code works fine when the ID is present...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($buffer);
$obj = $dom->getElementById('someid')->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

But when it is not I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName()
```

Which is fine and expected, but i'm not sure how to deal with this case properly, what 'if' or 'try catch' should I use to return a 'no data found' message instead?

I have tried for instance this:

```
$obj = $dom->getElementById('someid');
if($obj->length > 0){
   $rows = $obj->getElementsByTagName('tr');
}
```

Comment: The `getElementById` returns `NULL` if no element found with the id `someid` so `$obj` which is `NULL->length` makes no sense. So just do `if ($obj) { ...`

Answer (score 3):

```
$obj = $dom->getElementById('someid');
if (!empty($obj)) {
    $obj = $obj->getElementsByTagName('tr');
} else {
    echo "No data found";
}
```

Comment: yeah, basically empty checks for both NULL and blank results. You could even use is_null function of PHP or even shorter versions as suggested by people below. Though happy to be of any help :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Documentary `DOMDocument::getElementById()` returns `NULL` if the element is not found, so you have to check against a `NULL` value.
For example:

```
if($obj = $dom->getElementById("someid")){
  $obj->getElementsByTagName("tr");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the method may return NULL (acording to documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)), so check for not-null variable:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($buffer);
$el = $dom->getElementById('someid');
if($el) {
    $obj = $el->getElementsByTagName('tr');
} else {
    throw new Exception("Element with id 'someid' was not found");
}
```